# Application should skip the unity launcher

Tags: unity, launcher, python, gtk, pyqt

How can I skip the unity launcher for a (Py)Qt-app? 
As you see when running the code below, there is an icon in the launcher.
I don't need that icon because I manage the windows of that application by a menu in the unity top panel.

I could of course use devilspie and set `skip_taskbar`, but than I can't show the window again after it has been minimized.

Moreover, I know a Gtk-application that works as intended, but in contrast to my application, its GUI is generated by an .ui-file. There it is done by
 `<property name=”skip_taskbar_hint”> False < /property >`. I need this in PyQt.

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QMainWindow, QApplication

class MyApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(QMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyApp(None, "App")
    app.exec_()
```

EDIT:
`Qt.X11BypassWindowManagerHint` does remove the icon from the launcher, but makes the window always stay on top regardless if `Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint` is set or not.
So as a 2nd solution, does anyone know how to fix that?
I guess because X11 is now bypassed, no Flag will work.